# Live Reload sublime text 3 enable reload with delay 1500ms

Tags: sublimetext3, livereload

How do I make LiveReload refresh the page after 1500 milliseconds? I wrote to the Sublime support service, but I did not receive an answer, I also searched on Google - I also did not find an answer. I would be grateful if you could tell me how to set it up.